# Open a compressed SQLite database in Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, compression

In Python, is there a more or less hacky way to open a compressed SQLite database without having to write a temporary file somewhere?

Something like:

```
import bz2
import sqlite3

dbfile = bz2.BZ2File("/path/to/file.bz2", "wb")
dbconn = sqlite3.connect(dbfile)

cursor = dbconn.cursor()
...
```

This of course raises:

```
ValueError: database parameter must be string or APSW Connection object
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The underlying C-library directly uses the filename string. Thus there is no way to transparently work on it from Python.

See the [code on Github](https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite/blob/51c1a18eac3d1d14a052b09e3546dd0c4ce70638/src/connection.c#L113)

Depending on your OS, you might be able to use a RAM-disk to work on the file. If your sqlite-file is bigger than that, it might be time to switch to another DB-system, like Postgres.

Comment: Thank you, [PyFilesystem](http://docs.pyfilesystem.org/) might be able to give me a cross-platform ramdisk